# Saving HttpSession in redis on springboot REST call

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis

I cannot manage to get my session saved inside a redis db when making a API call.

I want to save the session created by a specific API call inside redis.

For this I am using the SpringBoot redis configuration:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis")
compile group: 'org.springframework.session', name: 'spring-session-data-redis', version: '2.0.4.RELEASE'
```

I have followed the setup instructions here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/boot-redis.html.

I want that when my client calls my API endpoint, the JSESSIONID to be saved as a HASH inside the redis  that I can append data to that hash and retrive it later.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Please add the snippet of the code you have tried so far.

Comment: I did not add anything special, the tutorial that followed said only to add the `spring-session-data-redis` dependecy and configure `spring.session.store-type=redis # Session store type.`